# A person who knows how to read but cannot write

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call somebody who can read but cannot write?

I found the term **semiliterate**, the [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/semiliterate) says

> 1. Having achieved an elementary level of ability in reading **and** writing.

But [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/semi-literate) defines it as

> **semi-literate**: Unable to read **or** write with ease or fluency; poorly educated:

I want a word that means a person who *only* knows how to read. Is there such a word?

Comment: Definitely a duplicate. *Agraphic* seems the best choice.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is any specific word but there are three that come close enough:

1. A dysgraphic is someone who has difficulty in writing, but may still be able to write.
2. A completely paralysed literate is someone who can read but cannot move any part of his body and thus, cannot be said to be able to write, at least not physically.
3. Find someone you know who can read but cannot write. His or her name is the one you are looking for.